# How prepare and transfer database from mysql 5.7 to 8.0.19 since mysql_upgrade has been removed

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysql-8.0

I noticed that the mysql_upgrade script is no longer available with mysql 8.0.16, and I'm running 8.0.19, so after creating a database backup from version 5.7 and imported to the version 8.0.19.

So, there's anything else I need to do to make sure to use the database in the new server running ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 1):

Do a logical dump with `mysqldump` instead of physical backup with `xtrabackup` or similar tool.

You will need no additional conversions. `mysql_upgrade` script is intended to convert physical storage files into the new version after in-place software upgrade. If you have pumped the dump onto the freshly installed MySQL, you can omit that script completely.

Answer (score 1):

Per the official documentation, they mention the usage of mysql_upgrade is no longer necessary when trying to restore in MySQL 8.0.16 or later.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-enterprise-backup/8.0/en/restore-upgrade.html

I guess you should be fine, even though this question is old. How did it went? did you had any issue?